liquibase cassandra to check status with server with ssl
I am trying to connect to a cassandra server with sqlsh using a command
sqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042 --ssl
and configured the authentication, and certfile and other parameter in the configuration file. and I am able to login with the server.
But when I tried liquibase to connect with the same server with the url: jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9042/keyspacename?compliancemode=liquibase&localDatacenter=datacenter1
I am getting an error com.datatax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid address.
I need to pass the certfile in the liquibase.properties file or something not sure how to fix this error.
Does anyone resolve this type of issue?
Thanks,
Map
I set enablessl=true and encrypt=false, and add the driver in the liquibase.property file.
